# Celery with redis as a queue - I cant find a way to find out what tasks are prefetched

Tags: python, redis, queue, celery, inspect

Is there some way, how to retrieve info on tasks that are prefetched in celery with Redis as a queue?

This prefetched tasks are like ghosts. They are not being processed nor are waiting in the queue so I for redis they are invisible.

With rabbitMQ+celery I could see all tasks (combining the both's API). But with redis, I cant see anything (Actually I could only count tasks in the queue -> which is wrong, because tasks in the queue equals prefetched + queued). Celery's inspect is also not helpful.

Is there some simple solution, does redis has some nice API in **python** with which I could see where are my tasks?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. The inspect API gives you ability to inspect `reserved` tasks. It is covered in the [Commands section](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#commands) of the Celery documentation. Something like `celery -A yourproj.app inspect registered` should give you prefetched tasks of each worker. If you do not see anything in the output, that means there are no reserved tasks at that particular moment.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. I know about reserved, yet I am getting prefetched tasks only for one queue out of 4. Other queues are totally invisible

Comment: Most of the time you will see nothing, until your cluster becomes very busy.